# Fail to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404. in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist

Tags: python, django, web

I'm trying to put image on my website with Django. But it always give an error 404, Tried many things, but it still be the problem.

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'



{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<img src="{% static 'media/logo2.jpeg' %}" alt="photo" height="100" width="500">

<p>HEllo world</p>

{% block content %}
replace me
{% endblock %}



</html>
```

Wanna to have image on the website!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide project tree and urls.py. You can follow Django's official documentation. To check [click here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)

You can also try using this code snippet:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```